# IE11 Taking focus from form and holding it

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a form page that, while tabbing through near the end, rather than going to the next input field focus jumps to IE's own selectables (url bar, tabs, etc), and won't go back to page elements *at all*. It only cycles around the browser options. Even clicking an earlier input field to focus that then hitting tab once puts you back in the url bar.

This is a weird one, no amount of searching has found a single other person mentioning similar. It appears to be completely EI's fault, but I have to deal with it somehow. The site I develop for has to be completely keyboard accessible per the [WCAG2.0](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag), and this is a hard stop currently.

I've tested it quite a bit and found a bit of info, though the specifics I've found only make it stranger.
It seems to be related to the fixed footer IE adds to deliver notes about saved form info or partial loading and such. For one, if such footer doesn't appear at all, the page works fine. It there is the footer, when the tab jumps out it will land there if it still exists; if it has been closed by clicking then the jump will be to the url. Here is the interesting bit though- if you tab into it and close it by hitting enter with focus over the x, then the page works perfectly after that! The next tab after hitting close puts focus back where it was, and it then continues as normally expected. It has to be closed by keyboard though, closing with mouse leave the page totally focus-cursed unless you refresh.
The jump out point is always the same tabbing down, but if you click focus below that and shift+tab up it does still jump out, but between a higher point. With form elements wxyz, it is between y and z going down, but between y and x going up, so in either case it is upon leaving x.

Any ideas at all?

Edit2: I've been cleared to link the site. It occurs on [South Moon Under](http://www.southmoonunder.com/)'s billing page. To get there, you have to put something in the cart, hit (guest) checkout, and fill+click passed the shipping page (dumby info is fine for this, Mr. Test). On the billing page nothing needs to be filled to see the issue, just tab down; the jump is between the giftcard number and pin fields. (reminder: only occurs if IE's footer appeared, and is worst if you closed it by mouse.)

Edit: The form is totally normal HTLM, and works fine in all other cases and browsers. I can post the code but it isn't interesting.

```
<div class="formfield giftcertfield">
        <label class="label" for="dwfrm_billinggiftcert_giftCertCode">
                <span class="requiredindicator">*</span>
                <span class="labeltext">Redeem Gift Card:</span>
        </label><!-- END: label -->
        <div class="value">
                <input class="textinput required" id="dwfrm_billinggiftcert_giftCertCode" type="text" name="dwfrm_billinggiftcert_giftCertCode" value="" maxlength="2147483647">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <br>
        <label class="label" for="dwfrm_billinggiftcert_giftCertCodePin">
                <span class="requiredindicator">*</span>
                <span class="labeltext">Pin Number:</span>
        </label><!-- END: label -->
        <div class="value">
             <input class="textinput required" id="dwfrm_billinggiftcert_giftCertCodePin" type="text" name="dwfrm_billinggiftcert_giftCertCodePin" value="" maxlength="2147483647">
        </div>
```

...And then a couple more buttons and such. The jump happens between these two inputs though (going down, it is between the first here and a checkbox in a different form going up.)

Comment: You can link, but you should try to create a small reproduction of the issue

Comment: I'm assuming you have set a tab-index property?

Comment: @Mark The page does not have a unique tabindex for every element in order, as the default progression works well in general. There are a couple tabindex="0" to add to flow and "-1" for skip link targets though.  You can see for yourself soon though, as I'm about to add the link.

Comment: @Jigokuro i tested your site on IE11 and tabbed through the site and everything worked fine. I tested in Chrome and it tabbed exactly the same for me. One random issue i saw in both browsers is when you tab on to the sign-up email button submit the text disappears.

Comment: Thanks for your time, @crazymatt. That is a weird one with the email button; the value actually changes from "Join Now" to null... must be something off in the validation js. 
The big error, however, only occurs on the billing page.